# How to load/open Registry Class Diagram .CD file?

Tags: visual-studio, registry, class-diagram

How we can open **Registry Class Diagram (.CD) file** ? If we directly double click on it then it tries to open in Visual Studio and shows following error message [image] :

> "Class Diagram are not supported by this project type."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can open such Registry Class Diagram (.CD) file by loading it into Registry Editor. Follow the steps to load .CD file in Registry Editor.

```
 1. Open regedit.  
 2. GoTo File->Load Hive..    
 3. Select your .CD file.    
 4. Give a temporary key name <XYZ>. (under this key, .CD file will get imported) 
 5. Click Ok.
```

And then you can see the registry keys those are imported from .CD file under Registry key XYZ.
To unload this registry, follow the same steps (Unload Hive).